# What caused a sudden jump and shut down on VM in Azure

Tags: azure

[image]

Hi there,

I am really curious about the VM in Azure that had a sudden jump of usage and temporarily shut down without me knowing although I had not done anything at the moment. 
Is there anyone who can explain what was happening?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: It's really impossible to know what is happening within your VM, as there are no additional details provided. As for shutdown, perhaps you enabled auto-shutdown (though that wouldn't explain a "temporary" shutdown). I'd also suggest moving this question to ServerFault, as it's off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Generally Azure VM can have the auto shutdown setup will creating the image. Can you check your settings? Refer the link below.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/announcing-auto-shutdown-for-vms-using-azure-resource-manager/#:~:text=Go%20to%20your%20VM%20blade,15%20minutes%20before%20auto%2Dshutdown.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management

Comment: This would be best as a comment, vs an answer, as there's really no way to really know what the OP's issue is. (also, the question itself should be on another site, such as ServerFault, as it's not a programming question).

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately, I don't have comment rights yet :(